# MySQL query date by format like MMYY

Tags: mysql, sql, date, date-formatting

I have a table with expiration CB cards dates in format MMYY (example: `0322`). I want to query cards which will expire in the next month.

I know about `DATE_FORMAT`, but when I try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM payment_way WHERE expiration_date <= DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%m%y")
```

I have cards with `expiration_date` like: `0523`

How can I select expiration dates for the next month? I thought I had a good way with `DATE_FORMAT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
where expiration_date = date_format(now() + interval 1 month, '%m%y')
```

You should also fix the expiration date so it is stored using a more standard format.  At least YYYYMM, if not a proper date.

If you want either this month or next month, I would suggest:

```
where expiration_date in (date_format(now(), '%m%y'), date_format(now() + interval 1 month, '%m%y'))
```

Both of these are index-safe, so they can use an index on your column.

Comment: Ok nice ! it just seems the comparison (> or <) doesn't work, but equality does... I was just stuck with my poor query, but yeah forgot about comparison and String format I guess

Comment: And thanks for "either this month or next month" syntax !